# MongoDB Java driver - problems with aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

In Java with MongoDB driver I want to have pairs (business_name, count), meaning reviews count per business. Currently I have aggregate pipeline:

```
Bson group = group("$business_id", Accumulators.sum("count", 1));
Bson lookupOperation = lookup(
  "business",
  "_id",
  "business_id",
  "business_data"
);
Bson unwind = unwind("$business_data");
Bson project = project(fields(include("business_data.name", "count"), excludeId()));

return db
  .getCollection("tip")
  .aggregate(Arrays.asList(group, lookupOperation, unwind, project));
```

It works, but returns:

```
Document{{count=1, business_data=Document{{name=Firestone Complete Auto Care}}}}
```

1) How can I unwind `business_data.name` to have `{count, name}`?

2) How can I make name distinct? I want only 1 count per name, but printing results gives many identical copies, e. g.:

```
Document{{count=3, business_data=Document{{name=Malmaison}}}}
Document{{count=3, business_data=Document{{name=Malmaison}}}}
```

3. Results are quite big collection, so I return AggregateIterable, but I want results sorted by name. Can I do that with iterable, without loading entire data into array and sorting the array?

**EDIT**

Business document example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ddbc3c1a94f7aac8d179b7c"),
    "business_id" : "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA",
    "full_address" : "4840 E Indian School Rd\nSte 101\nPhoenix, AZ 85018",
    "hours" : {
        "Tuesday" : {
            "close" : "17:00",
            "open" : "08:00"
        },
        "Friday" : {
            "close" : "17:00",
            "open" : "08:00"
        },
        "Monday" : {
            "close" : "17:00",
            "open" : "08:00"
        },
        "Wednesday" : {
            "close" : "17:00",
            "open" : "08:00"
        },
        "Thursday" : {
            "close" : "17:00",
            "open" : "08:00"
        }
    },
    "open" : true,
    "categories" : [ 
        "Doctors", 
        "Health & Medical"
    ],
    "city" : "Phoenix",
    "review_count" : 7,
    "name" : "Eric Goldberg, MD",
    "neighborhoods" : [],
    "longitude" : -111.983758,
    "state" : "AZ",
    "stars" : 3.5,
    "latitude" : 33.499313,
    "attributes" : {
        "By Appointment Only" : true
    },
    "type" : "business"
}
```

Review document example:

```
{
    "user_id": "IORZRljfUkedhh1SGMthTA",
    "text": "The desserts are enormous..dear god.",
    "business_id": "JwUE5GmEO-sH1FuwJgKBlQ",
    "likes": 0,
    "date": "2011-09-29",
    "type": "tip"
}
```

Comment: Please post a of sample input documents you are querying on.

Comment: @prasad_ I added that info in edit

Comment: You can try adding these two stages and see if it helps: `group("$business_data.name", first("count", "$count")),` _and_ `project(fields(computed("name", "$_id"), include("count"), excludeId()))`.